# Zooming UIScrollView under UIView which receiving touches

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming, uigesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

There are two views.

The first is an `UIScrollView` where the view to zoom is placed.
The second is an `UIView` which can handle taps on it.

Both views have gesture recognizers attached to them.

The problem is that even all gesture recognizers are turned off, scroll view won't zoom until I completely remove a view above (or set it `userInteractionEnabled = NO`). So how can I pass touches to scroll view and not lose other recognizers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just add scroll's gesture recognizers to this custom view

```objective-c
@implementation CustomView

- (void)overridePinchForScroll:(UIScrollView *)scroll
{
    [self addGestureRecognizer:scroll.panGestureRecognizer];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:scroll.pinchGestureRecognizer];
}

@end
```

`Note.` You should add both pan and pinch gesture recognizers, because if you only add a pinch recognizer, it'll throw an error:

`Ignoring call to [UIPanGestureRecognizer setTranslation:inView:] since gesture recognizer is not active.`

And, of course, thus you'll still be able to drag zoomed content.